# Specifying flywayUrl through system property in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, database-migration, flyway

Using [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) with [sbt](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt/) how can the `flywayUrl` be specified through system properties (`-D`) instead of via `build.sbt`?

I want to run the migrations via command line, specifying all parameters (driver, url, user, password) without defining them in `build.sbt`.

The plugin [documentation page](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt/) seems to indicate that this should be possible:

> **Overriding order**
>
> System properties > Plugin configuration

I've tried running it like this:

```
sbt -Dflyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:target/foobar -Dflyway.user=SA flywayMigrate
```

But the `flyway.url` property seems to be ignored in favor of the `flywayUrl` property defined in `build.sbt`.

Considering a project with these files:

#### build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.174"
)

seq(flywaySettings: _*)

flywayUrl := "something that should be overriden"
```

#### project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.googlecode.flyway" % "flyway-sbt" % "2.3")

resolvers += "Flyway" at "http://flywaydb.org/repo"
```

#### src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__Create_person_table.sql

```
create table PERSON (
    ID int not null,
    NAME varchar(100) not null
);
```

Running this command:

```
$ sbt -Dflyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:target/foobar -Dflyway.user=SA flywayMigrate
```

Produces this error:

```
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading project definition from /home/fernando/work/scratch/flyway-sbt/foobar/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/fernando/work/scratch/flyway-sbt/foobar/project/}foobar-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to foobar (in build file:/home/fernando/work/scratch/flyway-sbt/foobar/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/fernando/work/scratch/flyway-sbt/foobar/}foobar...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid JDBC URL (should start with jdbc:) : something that should be overriden
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:82)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$FlywayOps$.configure$extension1(FlywayPlugin.scala:214)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$FlywayOps$.configure$extension0(FlywayPlugin.scala:207)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$Flyway$.apply(FlywayPlugin.scala:193)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$$anonfun$flywaySettings$26$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcI$sp(FlywayPlugin.scala:145)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$$anonfun$flywaySettings$26$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FlywayPlugin.scala:145)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$$anonfun$flywaySettings$26$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FlywayPlugin.scala:145)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$.withContextClassLoader(FlywayPlugin.scala:184)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$.com$googlecode$flyway$sbt$FlywayPlugin$$withPrepared(FlywayPlugin.scala:167)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$$anonfun$flywaySettings$26.apply(FlywayPlugin.scala:145)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.sbt.FlywayPlugin$$anonfun$flywaySettings$26.apply(FlywayPlugin.scala:145)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:flywayMigrate) com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid JDBC URL (should start with jdbc:) : something that should be overriden
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 7, 2014 3:32:39 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The following is the definition of flywayUrl](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-sbt/src/main/scala/com/googlecode/flyway/sbt/FlywayPlugin.scala#L37):

```
val flywayUrl = settingKey[String]("The jdbc url to use to connect to the database.")
```

I can't seem to find how the setting could be set through the system property. The plugin doesn't seem to support it.

With that said, you should find the following `build.sbt` a solution and be able to set its value through an appropriate system property:

```
flywayUrl := System.getProperty("flyway.url", "[default]")
```

When `sbt` executed with no `flyway.url` set:

```
$ sbt 'show flywayUrl'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to flyway (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/flyway/)
[info] [default]
```

And when it is set on command line:

```
$ sbt -Dflyway.url=command-line 'show flywayUrl'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to flyway (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/flyway/)
[info] command-line
```

You may also find the other question [Setting value of setting on command line when no default value defined in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939554/setting-value-of-setting-on-command-line-when-no-default-value-defined-in-build) useful.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense. I'll verify it.

Comment: Thanks, @Jacek. Using `getProperty` to set the value solved my issue. Now I understand sbt a little bit better. But I believe the line starting with `lazy val flywayUrl` should not be in my build.sbt. It causes an error: reference to flywayUrl is ambiguous - it is imported twice in the same scope. Unless I misunderstood something, I think it would be better left out of the answer.

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you as it's improved my knowledge on SBT, too! As to `lazy val flywayUrl`, you're right, you should remove it as it's already defined in the plugin. Happy SBTing! :)

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer and removed the redundant line. Thanks.