# How to set fork in Test when -jvm-debug given on command line?

Tags: sbt

Is there a way to conditionally disable forking if the project is run in debug mode:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999
```

Then in my build:

```
fork in Test := { 
  //find a key that lets me know if debugging in set up
  !isDebugging.value
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Specifying flywayUrl through system property in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634326/specifying-flywayurl-through-system-property-in-sbt) should be of some help.

Add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val isDebugging = settingKey[Boolean]("true when xdebug is true; false otherwise")

isDebugging := System.getProperty("xdebug") == "true"

fork in Test := !isDebugging.value
```

When you execute `sbt -Dxdebug=true` it gives you what you want.

BTW I see no references to `jvm-debug` in the SBT sources, but it is indeed in the shell script I'm using to fire it up. It could be that you'd have to change `sbt-launch-lib.bash` to accommodate the change to add `xdebug` when `-Xdebug` is set.

Comment: jvm-debug:
* docs: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/6930c304284a897c33e7e6bdd77e0a4812f6698e/sbt#L291
* impl: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/6930c304284a897c33e7e6bdd77e0a4812f6698e/sbt#L153-L156

Comment: This did not work for me. I use System.getEnv("usedebug") == "true" instead and added a ```alias sbtd="usedebug=true sbt -jvm-debug 5005"``` to my .bashrc to start the debugger and have the env set and now it doesn't fork when I use that command

Answer (score 2):

Jacek's suggestion is pointing to the right direction, but couldn't work for me (or even at all?). `System.getProperty` cannot retrieve `-Xdebug` flag set by an sbt's Bash script basically - when calling `System.getProperties`, `-Xdebug` is not listed there, likewise any other non-standard JVM property (like `-Xmx` for example).

What's worked for me is this:

```
lazy val isDebug = settingKey[Boolean]("true when -Xdebug is set, false otherwise")

isDebug := ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments.contains("-Xdebug")

fork in Test := !isDebug.value
```

Cheers!