# How to run sbt tests for debugging when debug is disabled by default?

Tags: scala, debugging, sbt

I find it incredibly awkward to have to restart sbt with special flags if I want to run the tests (or a main) with debug enabled. It's also a pain if the main or test is usually in a forked JVM:

[How to set fork in Test when -jvm-debug given on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729554)

Is there any **simple** way to conditionally do a `run`, `test`, `test-quick` or `test-only` and ask for debugging to be enabled in the forked process? e.g. with syntax like `test-only -jdb`

I don't really want to have to write my own `Task`s to do this... maintaining them is going to be a nightmare. But I guess that would allow syntax like `module/jdb:test-only`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any simple feature that enables debugging out of the box.

[As you mentioned on sbt-dev list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sbt-dev/bHOwIVKB9gM/GGHBWKptCzYJ), making a custom configuration like `debug:testOnly` sounds like a good strategy.

Answer (score 4):

While Eugene accurately mentions that we could provide `debug:testOnly` out of the box, the following should help you out:

```
val DebugTest = config("dtest") extend Test

lazy val myproject =
  project.configs(DebugTest).
  settings(inConfig(DebugTest)(Defaults.testSettings):_*).
  settings(
    fork in DebugTest := true,
    javaOptions in DebugTest += "debugging options",
    definedTests in DebugTest := (definedTests in Test).value
  )
```

This should allow you to do `dtest:testOnly *`, `dtest:run` and `dtest:test` on `myproject`. The forked JVM (note `fork in DebugTest := true`) will use whatever `debugging options` you've provided.

Comment: cool, thanks! I wrote something like this in https://github.com/fommil/lions-share/blob/master/sbt/src/main/scala/LionPlugin.scala so this makes sense.