# How to specify "fork in Test := false" from command line rather than from build.sbt in a play framework based project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

To keep the question as short as possible I just need to know if there's a way to set fork to false directly from the command line when launching activator instead of hard coding it as follows "**fork in Test := false**" from under **build.sbt** in a play-framework 2.4 based project.

**__________________All below is for further context___________________**

I'm maintaining a "legacy" project based on play framework version 2.4, and been trying to configure my IntelliJ environment to enable debugging with unit tests. To  achieve this I created 2 run configurations, the first launches activator in debug mode and pipes all its output to IntelliJ console, the second attaches the debugger to the formerly launched jvm. I'm then free to run and debug any tests as I please from activator's prompt.

In order for the debugger to work though, I have to add the following to my build.sbt:

```
fork in Test := false
```

which allows for debugging with my IntelliJ project setup, since I have it properly configured to take my "**conf/test-config.conf**" into consideration when launching activator. But when I simply run "activator test" from a native command line console, **with the fork option set to false**, activator ignores my **test-config.conf** file (obviously with  configurations tuned for unit tests) and instead loads the original app config file "**application.conf**" causing my tests to fail with all sorts of conflicts. This happens even with the below configuration in my **build.sbt**:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test-application.conf"
```

Commenting out "**fork in Test := false**" fixes the problem when I launch the tests from a native console (the unit tests run properly), my IntelliJ launch configuration also succeeds to run the tests but the problem is it loses its ability to debug the code, which is actually the whole point in the first place.

Here's the command I'm currently using from IntelliJ to launch activator in debug mode:

```
java -Dactivator.home=<activator-home-path> -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dconfig.file=conf/test-application.conf -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9990 -jar <activator-jar-path>
```

Comment: `set fork in Test := false`

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Using of `sbt`s `settingKey` as described in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729554/how-to-set-fork-in-test-when-jvm-debug-given-on-command-line) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Will give this a look if shabaz suggestion doesn't work, thanks!

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following command when using **sbt**:

```
sbt "set fork in Test := false" test
```

For **activator**, you can try the following:

Add this to your build.sbt:

```
fork in Test :=  Option(System.getProperty("fork")) match {
  case Some("false") => false
  case _ => true
}
```

And then sumply run the following command:

```
activator -Dfork=false test
```

Comment: Will try this out at work tomorrow, play 4.2 uses activator (instead of sbt) though, I hope this still applies. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: First suggestion ignores my build.sbt, second doesn't compile, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729554/how-to-set-fork-in-test-when-jvm-debug-given-on-command-line solved my problem